# TypeScript type inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference

In the following code, I try to create a type-safe function that access the `data` property of the given input. My goal is to avoid repeating the access to `data` everywhere, and for this to be worth it I would like to keep boilerplate to a minimum (e.g. I would like TypeScript to infer as many type as possible).

```
interface User {
    name: string
}

interface HttpResponse<T> {
    data: T
    status: number
}

type HttpPromise<T> = Promise<HttpResponse<T>>

function fetch<T>(url: string): HttpPromise<T> {
    return
}

function getData<T>(response: HttpResponse<T>): T {
    return response.data
}

// Doesn't work: 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<User>'.
function fetchUser(): Promise<User> {
    return fetch('https://...').then(getData)
}
```

I know how to make it work by explicitly stating more types, but I don't know why this doesn't work already. In particular:

1. Where does the `{}` type come from (in `Promise<{}>`)?
2. Why can't TypeScript infer the type of the expression properly, based on the return type?

[Link to TypeScript's playground with the code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20HttpResponse%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20T%0A%20%20%20%20status%3A%20number%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20HttpPromise%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Promise%3CHttpResponse%3CT%3E%3E%0A%0Afunction%20fetch%3CT%3E(url%3A%20string)%3A%20HttpPromise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20getData%3CT%3E(response%3A%20HttpResponse%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20response.data%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Doesn%27t%20work%3A%20%27Promise%3C%7B%7D%3E%27%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20%27Promise%3CUser%3E%27.%0A%2F%2F%201)%20Where%20does%20the%20%27%7B%7D%27%20type%20come%20from%3F%0A%2F%2F%202)%20Why%20can%27t%20TypeScript%20infer%20the%20type%20properly%3F%0Afunction%20fetchUser()%3A%20Promise%3CUser%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fetch(%27https%3A%2F%2F...%27).then(getData)%0A%7D%0A)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with solution:

```
function fetchUser(): Promise<User> {
    return fetch<User>('https://...').then(getData)
}
```

In order for type inference to work we need to give TypeScript a starting point, which in this case is the function with which we initiate the execution. If we let *fetch* method generic T parameter to have a default value (which is {}) then TypeScript will use that type to determine all connected function calls, basically making *then* and *getData* to inherit that default type. In the end, when TypeScript gets to the point when it have to verify type correctness between last function signature (*getData*) and outer *fetchUser* signature it will discover conflict, because *getData* is assumed to work with {} type and *fetchUser* states explicitly that it works with User type.

You can compare how TypeScript will work out returned type when you omit completely the type returned by fetchUser function:

```
function fetchUser() {
    return fetch<User>('https://...').then(getData)
}
```

If you hover over *fetchUser* function you will see that TypeScript inferred the User type from inner *fetch* function signature and its still Promise< User>.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, the reason why TypeScript is complaining about the type being `Promise<{}>` is that, if you don't specify a type for a generic function that returns a promise, it's by default `Promise<{}>`.

With this in mind, by calling `fetch('http://...')`, without providing the type parameter, TypeScript will *infer* that it's `Promise<HttpResponse<{}>>`.

I assume you were able to make it work by specifying the `User` type when calling `fetch` in  `fetchUser`, like so:

```
return fetch<User>('https://...').then(getData);
```

The inference that you're looking for would've worked if you were returning the call to `fetch` directly. Something like:

```
async function getValueAsync<T>(): Promise<T> {
    return null;
}

function testGetValueAsync(): Promise<User> {
    return getValueAsync();
}
```

However, since you're chaining off of that call, there is nothing in the `fetch` call that tells TypeScript what type it's returning.

Therefore, the minimal change you need to make is to specify the `User` type when calling `fetch`

```
return fetch<User>('https://...').then(getData);
```